# Массив в C#, код вместо индекса

Tags: c#, массивы

В php есть нечто такое:

```
$array = array('name'=>"Vasia", 'lastName'=>"Pupkin", 'Hello World');
```

И можно обращаться не по индексу, а по коду что-ли. Есть ли способ делать так же в C#? Или для этого есть `dictionary`?

Comment: для этого есть Dictionary

Comment: @PashaPash, на самом деле, так как в примере в вопросе, нельзя сделать с Dictionary

Comment: @Grundy да,  'Hello World' в конце помешает

Comment: Эта структура данных называется `ассоциативный массив` и в C# ее роль выполняет `Dictionary`: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ассоциативный_массив

Answer (score 3):

Для этого в C# используется Dictionary

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> //В dictionary можно использовать инициализацию
{
    { "name", "Vasya"},
    { "lastName", "pupkin" }
};

dictionary.Add("middleName", "Ivanovich"); //В dictionary можно добавлять пары ключ -> значение

var name = dictionary["name"]; //По ключу
```

Comment: `var lastName = dictionary.ElementAt(1).Value` может не прокатить, так как порядок в словаре не гарантируется

Comment: По индексу (помимо последовательного перебора) не гарантируется порядок ключей.

Comment: Ну вообще порядок изменится, если мы удаляли значение из словаря, но да, на это пожалуй закладываться не стоит, удалю эту строку.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще подобные задачи в C# решаются при помощи `Dictionary`.
В Вашем примере у последнего значения не было бы (*либо ключа, либо значения*). Можно конечно же *либо ключ либо значение* указать как (`null`) и дело в шляпе, но легких путей мы не ищем :)

Немного **костыль**, но все же:

```
var tuple = new Tuple<string[], string[], string>(new string[] { "Name", "Vasya" },
    new string[] { "Lastname", "Pupkin" },
    "Hello, world !");

string value = tuple.Item1;
if (value[0] == "Name")
{
    Console.WriteLine(true);
}
```

Comment: Ключ не может быть null'ом.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо за поправку, оговорился :)